# Dynatable broke with Dynamic HTML Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatable

I have created a Dynatable, I have dynamically crafted the Table Headers.
Dynatable gives an error when it is run as it cant find the Headers in the HTML.

> ERROR:Uncaught Error: Couldn't find any columns headers in 'thead tr
>   th,td'. If your header row is different, specify the selector in the
>   table: headRowSelector option.

SEE FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0ycqnaxg/6/

It does work somewhat if the HTML contains:

Working FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0ycqnaxg/9/

```
<thead>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
  </thead>
```

But i have left the thead blank in order to allow the dynamic creation.

Comment: If you populate the table do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes it works fine see updated working fiddle above

Comment: The reason why is here https://github.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/blob/master/jquery.dynatable.js#L447 It expects to be able to calculate `$columns.length` otherwise it throws an error

Comment: the array length property does work though? hResponse.length = 3

Comment: It's not the length of your javascript array that Dynatable looks for, it specifically searches for `th` and `td` elements that exist on the DOM. As long as `obj.$element.find(settings.table.headRowSelector).children('th,td');` (mearning there are no elements that are found - this code can be found in the link above) returns `null` you will get the same error which is why populating the table doesn't return an error

Comment: I see but, i have recreated the same structure using     $('#my-table thead').append('<th>' + value + '</th>');
I still dont understand why Dynatable cannot see it. If I view source on the rendered pages, the <th> items are there, It works if i create them manually using the same structure, am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Dynatable uses 'thead tr' as the headRowSelector when the headers are created dynamically and it searches for 'th' under that. The easy solution is to explicitely specify 'thead' as the headRowSelector.

```
$('#my-table').dynatable({
    table: {
        headRowSelector:'thead',
    },
    dataset: {
        records: columns
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have switched to using Datatables. 
Its the solution for me, just not the exact solution to this question.
For future reference, datatables allows you to create the headers dynamically based on an array of column headers;

```
$('#example thead tr,tfoot tr').append('<th>' + value + '</th>');
```

Comment: the OP requires a solution using dynatables